# "Where" vs "Where...to..."

Tags: questions, where

In many languages, there is a different word for "Where" and "Where-to" (German "Wo" vs "Wohin", Spanish "Dónde" vs "Adónde", Hungarian "Hol" vs "Hova"...) Now, "Where-to" and "Whither", though convenient, are archaisms in English... So, how to express the difference between "location" and "direction"? How would you ask the question more precisely in order to avoid confusion? For example, in the following case:

- Question: Where are they running?
- Possible answer (1):They are running at the stadium. (i.e. location)
- Possible answer (2): They are running home. (i.e. direction)

Comment: In Wales, we still sometimes say where-to. 'Pass me the spanner', 'Where to is it?'